# Setting globals in pytest class methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, pytest

I have an application that reads some config settings from a remote source upon startup and stores them in global scope. A function in this application uses a setting in that global config. Functionally it ends up looking something like this...

```
def define_globals():
    global MY_THRESHOLD
    MY_THRESHOLD = 123

def my_func(my_input):
    return my_input > MY_THRESHOLD

def run():
    define_globals()
    my_func(122)
```

I would like to test `my_func` using pytest but MY_THRESHOLD is not defined during the test. Kinda of new to testing so looked into fixtures a bit. Have something like this but still not finding that global when running the test.

```
import pytest
import my_file

@pytest.fixture()
def set_gloabls():
    global MY_THRESHOLD
    MY_THRESHOLD = 123

class TestMyApplication(object):

    @pytest.mark.usefixtures("set_gloabls")
    def test_my_func(self):
        assert my_file.my_func(122) == False
```

I guess I thought that a fixture would be working in the scope of the file being tested? IDK having a hard time groking how to do this without a code change in the application.

Comment: Remember that "global" variables are only global in the context of a module....so if your application is looking for `MY_THRESHOLD`, you would need to set that in the application module. I.e., if your test has `import myapp`, you would need to set `myapp.MY_THRESHOLD`. Can you show us your complete test file (including `import` lines)?

Comment: @larsks I'm simplifying the test file by a lot for the sake of example but I edited the test code to import from the application code. This is essentially what I have in real life.

Answer (score 0):

Re-iterating what I said in the comments, a "global" variable is only "global" in a module. So when you try to set `MY_THRESHOLD` in your test module, this is never going to be visible in your `my_file` module.

You would need to do something like this:

```
import pytest
import my_file

@pytest.fixture()
def set_globals():
    my_file.MY_THRESHOLD = 123

class TestMyApplication(object):

    @pytest.mark.usefixtures("set_globals")
    def test_my_func(self):
        assert my_file.my_func(122) == False
```

And in fact, since it's a global, you could also just do this (assuming that `MY_THRESHOLD` is a constant during your testing):

```
import pytest
import my_file

my_file.MY_THRESHOLD = 123

class TestMyApplication(object):

    def test_my_func(self):
        assert my_file.my_func(122) == False
```